# Where should I call subscriptions in React Redux Meteor.js mixture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, redux

I'm learning about Redux, and I think I have pretty good understanding of how it works, I understand the purpose of provider / store / actions / reducers.

I'm confused about where should I call subscriptions in my React / Redux / Meteor application.

I have seen examples on performing API calls in actions when using React / Redux apps.

Not sure what is the best / common used approach when we have Meteor.js in the mix, Should I call subscriptions in actions and pass them to reducers or vice versa.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since subscriptions are a bit different than a request to a REST api (typical example with Redux) so I don't create subscriptions in actions. Therefore, and assuming you're using `react-native-meteor`, I approach the problem in the same way as I would without Redux.

```
import Meteor, { createContainer } from 'react-native-meteor';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App = () => (
  <View />
);

export default createContainer(() => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('my-publication');
  const data = Meteor.collection('demo').find();

  return {
    ready: sub.ready(),
    data,
  };
}, connect()(App));
```

Hope that's of some value to you!

Comment: Thanks @spencercarli

Comment: Will this work for more conolicated applications? For example, subscribing at the root but searching a collection in a child component? I want the user to access different. Collections depending on the oage they are on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subscription to get loaded into your Redux store, then [`meteor-redux-middlewares`](https://github.com/samybob1/meteor-redux-middlewares) is super useful.  It gives you some sugar for making Redux actions that subscribe to publications and then dispatch new actions when the publication changes.

I tend to make a container component which looks to see if all the required data is available in the store and then calls one of the subscription actions if it isn't.